# How to make the notification text more readable?

Tags: mojave, notifications

I find it very hard to read the notification text especially when it appears on top of a black content.

[image]

It is more legible if it is against a lighter background:

[image]

Is there anyway I can make it more readable regardless of underlying content?

Also added the accessibility settings screenshot

[image]

Comment: I wonder if "reduce transparency" in Accessibility settings affects notification centre.

Comment: This doesn't look like the normal appearance for text in Mojave.  What version are you running?  Do you have any non-default or 3rd party UI running?

Comment: @ankii No. I added a screenshot of the settings

Comment: @fsb No third party UI

Comment: Looks like dark mode, have you tried changing that? I don't see any settings for changing those colors anywhere.

Comment: @SteveChambers weird that Sys Pref is light, but Firefox is dark, but then Terminal is light. Anthony: switch between dark mode and light mode to see if it changes. Also "Tick" the reduce transparency checkbox.